# how to install jdk1.6 in ubuntu

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the Sun Java JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5567/how-to-install-the-sun-java-jdk)

Hi all,recently i installed ubuntu in virual box inside the a windows os,but i'm unable to install the jdk in that ubuntu,can any one help me out?

Comment: here:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JavaInstallation and http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-install-java-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux/ and http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu.html and http://jdk-distros.java.net/ubuntu.html net is full of such web page search on it.

Comment: have you tried askubuntu.com? The stack exchange site for questions like this?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Comment: although this will install the open-jdk version which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

type `java` and follow the instructions

Comment: actually, I would type (ie, I typed) javac to make sure I got the JDK, not the JRE

Comment: indeed, but I'm hoping this is a skill that would teach more and be useful in future.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo synaptic`, search for `sun java`, mark it for installation, and click Apply.

Comment: thanks, but how to add envoronment variable to path

Comment: Just link /usr/bin/java to the installed java binary.

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:/home/user/path/to/executable` here path to `jdk/bin`

Comment: To add JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME to your environment variables, one usual way is to add their definition to `/etc/environment`

Comment: [Graphical applications should be run as root with `gksu`/`gksudo` (or `kdesudo` on Kubuntu), not directly with `sudo`.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)